# es.read.source.filter v.s. es.read.field.include when reading data with elasticsearch-hadoop

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, pyspark, elasticsearch-hadoop

When reading data from Elasticsearch with `elasticsearch-hadoop`, there are two options two specify how to reading a subset of fields from the source, according to [the offical documents](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/configuration.html), *i.e,*.

- `es.read.field.include`: *Fields/properties that are parsed and considered when reading the documents from Elasticsearch...*;
- `es.read.source.filter`: *...this property allows you to specify a comma delimited string of field names that you would like to return from Elasticsearch.*

Both can be set as a comma-separated string.
I have tested the two options, and find that only `es.read.field.include` works with expected results, but `es.read.source.filter` takes no effect (with all data fields returned).

**Question**: what is the difference of these two options? and why the option `es.read.source.filter` does not take effect?
Here is the code to reading data

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('TestSparkElasticsearch').getOrCreate()
es_options = {"nodes": "node1,node2,node3", "port": 9200}
df = spark.read\
    .format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql")\
    .options(**es_options)\
    .option("es.read.source.filter", 'sip,dip,sport,dport,protocol,tcp_flag')\
    .load("test_flow_tcp")
df.printSchema()  # return all the fields, the option not work

df = spark.read\
    .format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql")\
    .options(**es_options)\
    .option("es.read.field.include", 'sip,dip,sport,dport,protocol,tcp_flag')\
    .load("test_flow_tcp")
df.printSchema()  # only return specified fields as expected
```

**Updated**: `es.read.source.filter` is added in Elasticsearch 5.4 and I am using version 5.1. Hence the option is ignored. Nevertheless, the difference of these two options in newer version is still not clearly explained in the document?